# New naming convention? VS 2017 tell me that my private properties and methods should start with capital letter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am so confused. For years private members was named using camelCase but now I get "Naming rule violation" warning which says I should use PascalCase also for private members. Why? Is it only an error in my configuration or Microsoft suddenly decided to change naming convention?

Comment: Properties have always been PascalCase, regardless visibility. VS2K17 simply started to warn you by default

Comment: To add to what @AdrianoRepetti, the same goes for methods. Only private fields should follow camelCase.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto many tutorials say that everything with private modifier should be written in camelCase. I even have Microsoft's materials which says so. Is it something relatively new?

Comment: @user4230877 I have never seen that recommendation for C#.  Where exactly did you see this style?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This convention is also visible at msdn! So why VS2017 suddenly says something else?

Comment: @BJMyers Official MS course (an old one), msdn code samples etc.

Comment: @BJMyers It was a rule of thumb for me for many years: if it's private name it using camelCase. Now I upgraded to VS2017 and warnings say something else

Comment: @BJMyers Now I am super confused where I should use camelCase. Only parameters and local variables?

Comment: @user I honestly NEVER saw that convention (in C#, not JavaScript, TypeScript, MS Java implementation of which I can't even remember name,...). Of course from official documentation (code in the wild...probably, especially from programmers with a Java background). FxCop and StyleCop alway had similar warnings (as back as I can remember). In short...you've bee unlucky with those tutorials.

Comment: For private members it's less important but, well, get used to this convention (or customize VS to do not warn about it when working with legacy projects).

Comment: Visual J++. Brrrrrrrr

Comment: @user4230877 Parameters, local variables, and private *fields*.  I'm still having a hard time believing any MSDN documentation varies from this.

Comment: It is a bug know as 'we have chaged yoour minds about stuff'. Or how can one call a situation where the designer creates names the compiler then issues warnings for? You can turn off the warnings in the warnings pane.

Comment: @TaW I know I can turn these warnings off but the problem is what's proper naming convention. Was I wrong all the time? Should I start private member's names with capital letter?

Comment: I wouldn't dream of using Pacal case for a private field. But I don't care too much about 'properness'. and the changing handling within VS encourages me, imo. But the shop rules should be followed to avoid having each team member doing it differently.. In the end the question (sadly) is opinion-based.